# Using IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler interface in windows-rs

Tags: winapi, rust, automation, windows-rs

I am trying to use IUIAutomation::AddFocusChangedEventHandler using the official windows-rs crate, but in order to use it I need to implement the IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler interface, which I am at a lose on how to do in rust

It seems that I have to define a struct and use the implement macro on it:

```rust
#[implement(windows::Win32::UI::Accessibility::IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler)]
struct A{}
```

But no matter what I try to implement I get "IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler is not a class or interface"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found where the problem is
The implement macro has not been updated to use paths starting with "windows" instead of "Windows",
so just adding

```rust
use windows as Windows;
```

and using paths starting with "Windows" seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I believe this is no longer required. I wasn't able to pin down the exact version where this was fixed, but 0.28.0 at least compiles the code from the question.